# JavaFX: ObservableLists, ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to B

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm trying to create a GUI in JavaFX. I have a ListView I want to use to show some data. There are two types of possible sets of data I'd want to use, let's call them Cars and Bikes. When I press the corresponding button, I want to load the data I need. So far my controller class looks like this:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.util.Callback;


import java.util.List;

public class FXMLController {
    @FXML
    ListView lv_list;
    @FXML
    Button button_cars;
    @FXML
    Button button_bikes;


    List<Cars> cList;
    List<Bikes> bList;
    Server serv;

    private ObservableList observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void initScene szene) {
        /* initializes serv so it properly yields data */
    }


    public void listAllCars() {
        cList = serv.getAllCars();
        updateCarList();
    }

    private void updateCarList() {
        observableList.setAll(cList);
        lv_list.setItems(observableList);
        lv_list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Cars>, ListCell<Cars>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Cars> call(ListView<Cars> listView) {
                return new ListViewElemCars(); // creates stuff to populate the list
            }
        });
    }

    public void listAllBikes() {
        bList = serv.getAllBikes();
        updateBikeList();
    }

    private void updateBikeList() {
        observableList.setAll(bList);
        lv_list.setItems(observableList);
        lv_list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Bikes>, ListCell<Bikes>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Bikes> call (ListView<Bikes> listView) {
                return new ListViewElemBikes(); //same as with cars
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The listing methods happen whenever one of the buttons is pressed. The methods themselves work pretty well - if I press the buttons for cars, all the cars show up the way they're supposed to. Same goes for the bikes. However, when I try to press one after another, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cars cannot be cast to Bikes
```

I guess it's due the unchecked calls in the updateCarList/updateBikeList methods,  but I'm really at a loss here. I want to somehow be able to do this stuff with one ListView, but I don't really understand what's wrong here. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post more information about the line the exception is coming from? Maybe a couple of lines of the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the concrete types in the cells returned by the `cellFactory`s. The `ListView` will reuse the cells which results in a `ClassCastException` when the new item type is added to a cell that is not intended to display a item of the new type.

Even the following approach doesn't seem to work:

1. Clear the `items` list
2. Replace the `cellFactory`
3. Call `refresh()`
4. Add new `items`

This means you have to use cells that can handle all the item types or by replacing the whole `ListView`.